# Flex bin-debug line spacing different from bin-release

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

This one is driving me insane! For some reason, when I export a bin-release of my application, all my text fields have a different line spacing from that of the bin-debug version. How is this even possible?!

Has anyone else come across something like this before?

Answer (score 0):

never seen anything like it. can you programmatically check the value of the linespacing? If it is different, then override all methods, that modify the component's TextFormat to see where different values are assigned.